# calculating total sum of a column php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have the following code:

```
<td class="dataTableContent">
<?php
$cuttinglist_weight_query = tep_db_query("select op.orders_id, p.products_id, SUM(p.products_weight) as total_products_weight from " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " op  left join " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p on (op.products_id = p.products_id) where orders_id = '" . (int)$cuttinglist['orders_id'] . "'");
$cuttinglist_weight = tep_db_fetch_array($cuttinglist_weight_query);

echo $cuttinglist_weight['total_products_weight'];

?>

</td>
```

this prints the Total weight of Order column:

[image]

In the box below titled 'total weight to prepare', I need to show the total of the column, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: take a counter , add weight for each record to it , and then display at end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td class="dataTableContent">

    <?php
    $cuttinglist_weight_query = tep_db_query("select op.orders_id, p.products_id, SUM(p.products_weight) as total_products_weight from " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " op  left join " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p on (op.products_id = p.products_id) where orders_id = '" . (int)$cuttinglist['orders_id'] . "'");
    $cuttinglist_weight = tep_db_fetch_array($cuttinglist_weight_query);

    echo $cuttinglist_weight['total_products_weight'];

    if(!$totalSum){ $totalSum = 0; }
    $totalSum += $cuttinglist_weight['total_products_weight']
    ?>

</td>
```

then at the end in your cell just echo it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Total Weight To Prepare</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $totalSum; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```